# Forcing directory slashes on virtual directories with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I understand how to add directory slashes to actual directories, but I need to add trailing slashes on to virtual directories – so that, when a user visits        **example.com/website/blog/entries** (*where /blog & /entries are both virtual directories*), the URL address would physically change to: **example.com/website/blog/entries/**

Here is my current working htaccess code that works for converting fake/virtual directories into parameters for my php script:

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z_\-/.]+)$ index.php?file=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This **RewriteRule** makes **example.com/website/blog/entries/** look like **example.com/website/index.php?file=blog/entries/** to PHP only, not the user.

Here are some of the Rewrite Rules I have attempted to make work with no avail:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .*[^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}$1/ [L,R=301]

# -----------------------------------------------

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.+)/$
RewriteRule ^.+/$ %1 [R=301,L]
```

I believe the problem is because my current regex that converts virtual directories into a parameter looks for the directory names starting with "/", so when the site is installed not in the root folder ("/"), or if there is not a trailing slash, it redirects to something completely wrong. I can't write the folder path anywhere in my htaccess file, because the path will constantly be changing. For example, I can't use something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:8888/project/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Is there a way to force trailing slashes on real, and virtual directories, **BEFORE** converting the virtual directories into PHP parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should do what you need:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Put here the URL where .htaccess is located
RewriteBase /project/

# Redirect virtual URLs w/o trailing slash to URL with it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [R=301,QSA,L]

# pass virtual URLs into index.php as file argument
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([a-zA-Z_\-/.]+)$ index.php?file=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The rules are processed in the order as they appear in the config, thus the redirect is done before passing the data into index.php

Here is the version w/o using `RewriteBase` with hardcoded part of URL:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect virtual URLs w/o trailing slash to URL with it
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*[^/])$
RewriteRule .* %1/ [R=301,QSA,L]

# pass virtual URLs into index.php as file argument
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/?([a-zA-Z_\-/.]+)$
RewriteRule .* index.php?file=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: This is near perfect, and answers my question, except I have to avoid using static directory names. Do you know of a way to get the directory where the .htaccess file is located via request? Something like %{REQUEST_DIR} , that can grab the name of the directory without me physically writing "/project/"? Thank you for you answer!

Comment: @deraad see the updated answer. Should work as you expect even w/o the hardcoded `/project/`

Comment: I tried using it without the hardcoded "/project/" name as you've suggested, but it doesn't work, because it redirects to the wrong place. Instead, I wrote a PHP script to recreate the htaccess file with the name of the subdirectory the site it installed in.